# I need help integrating and using elFinder with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, integration, file-management, elfinder

I have been playing with this for a day and cannot seem to get it to work.

`elFinder` has many options for connections, such as `PHP` and `Python` among others. Someone made a third party `ASP.NET` connector for it and it was reported that it worked.

Here is the page for the `DLL` for it:

http://elfinderconnectornet.codeplex.com/releases/view/55319

I am having tremendous trouble figuring out how to hook the existing `elFinder` to `ASP.NET`.

I hope to find someone who has had some experience with this and can assist me. I'm not sure what other information I can give you.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: http://elfinderaspnet.codeplex.com/
For now it provides some basic functionality but seems to be usable.

Answer (score 2):

There's an even better option right now called [ElFinder.Net Connector](https://elfinder.codeplex.com/) hosted at CodePlex. The coordinator and main developer of the port Evgeny Noskov is a super considerate person and he listens to feedback and acts as you can read here in a discussion I posted:

[Add startPath and uploadMaxSize to connector options](https://elfinder.codeplex.com/discussions/441737)

---

I liked elFinder.Net so much that I wrote a post to showcase a simple use case that is a great fit for it:

[Manage folders & files in your ASP.NET MVC app with elFinder.Net](http://www.leniel.net/2013/04/manage-folders-and-files-in-your-aspnet-mvc-project-with-elfinder-net-file-manager.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did some modifications on your project and posted it as an answer. 
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

ElFinder is very easy to configure and use.

I did some research on 'Implementing ElFinder on multiple pages using MVC' and found ["ElFinder.Net Connector"](https://elfinder.codeplex.com/) *NOT AVAILABLE*.

Download the simple MVC sample project from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-bQMqpE_InLLVFtRFFBY1Z4RjA/view?resourcekey=0-PyKXyPbT95MOaiJInlsZdQ)